# ASP Classic / JS multi select filter

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, filtering

I am trying to create a filter to display records assigned to multiple groups not just one as currently set up below. Maybe via a checkbox.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

ASP classic with JS using microsoft access as database

```html
<form method="get" name="frmJumpMenu" id="frmJumpMenu">
  <div align="right"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
   <select name="jumpFilter" onChange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,0)">
    <option value="">** Filter Group **</option>
    <option  value="set_group.asp?filter=%%">Show All</option>
    <% while (!rsGroups.EOF) { %>
     <option value="set_group.asp<%=(rsGroups.Fields.Item("GROUP").Value)%>"><%=(rsGroups.Fields.Item("GROUP_LABEL").Value)%></option>
    <% rsGroups.MoveNext(); } 
      if (rsGroups.CursorType > 0) { 
        if (!rsGroups.BOF) rsGroups.MoveFirst();
      } 
      else { rsGroups.Requery(); 
      } %> </select> </font>
  </div> 
</form>         

    <% var rsUnack__filter = "%%"; if (String(Session("usergroup")) != "undefined" && String(Session("usergroup")) != "") { rsUnack__filter = String(Session("usergroup")); } %>

    function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'"); if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex;}
```

The code on set_group.asp

```
<% Session("usergroup") = Request.QueryString("filter").item %>
```

Setting up the filter to filter client side isnt an option as the page has a refresh every 60 seconds due to records being added / amended regularly. I am trying to learn so any help or advise would be appreciated. I know the select tag will need the multiple attribute.

Comment: To pass multiple values you'd need to remove the onchange and submit the values to the other page maybe using a submit button,the action attribute of the form should be the setgroup.asp page

Comment: Thank you for your comment i have tried to amend as suggested however the page content does not change. The URL displayed due to the query string is not as expected (expected to be the rsGroups.Fields.Item("GROUP")  values from the access database.) I believe that part of the issue this may not be working is due to  below but I am not sure . <%
var rsUnack__filter = "%%";
if (String(Session("usergroup")) != "undefined" &&
    String(Session("usergroup")) != "") {
  rsUnack__filter = String(Session("usergroup"));
}
%>
and
    Session("usergroup") = Request.QueryString("filter").item

Comment: Probably depends on how you are using Session("usergroup") later in the code. You might have to modify the search query to use `IN` instead of `LIKE` (I am just guessing here). If you could edit the question and show how the code looks currently, it might help

Comment: Can not edit as says there is to much code. rsUnack.Source = "SELECT *  FROM database_MAIN  WHERE STATUS = 'Open' AND TOGROUP LIKE '"+ rsUnack__filter.replace(/'/g, "''") + "'  ORDER BY [databaseNUM] ASC"; is the query. Togroup in main database is same groups as in settings database, Would like to be able to filter so can show multiple groups e.g Group 1, 2, 3 etc based on what is selected.
DATABASE MAIN DATABASE:  
 H1    |H2  | H3   |  H4  |    H5
 TOGROUP   STATUS   DESCRIPTION TYPE  databaseNUM 
SETTINGS DATABASE - 
GROUP    | GROUPLABEL
?filter=Group1  Group 1

Comment: You can try changing the LIKE to IN : `rsUnack.Source = "SELECT * FROM database_MAIN WHERE STATUS = 'Open' AND TOGROUP IN ("+ rsUnack__filter.replace(/'/g, "''") + ") ORDER BY [databaseNUM] ASC";`, But then when nothing is selected the dropdown, you will need to omit the TOGROUP condition in the query `rsUnack.Source = "SELECT * FROM database_MAIN WHERE STATUS = 'Open'  ORDER BY [databaseNUM] ASC";`